# How to change name of month in dateplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I produce the following chart:
[image]

I urgently need to change the month names to Malay, and since there's no package for it, I need to do it manually.

**In this case, change May to Mei** (Mar = Mac, Aug = Ogos, Oct = Okt, Dec = Dis all need changing too, but let's use one for example).

How can I do this?

Code for above:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date, vix
2019-05-05, 13.66
2019-05-12, 17.86
2019-05-19, 17.26
2019-05-26, 15.76
2019-06-02, 17.85
2019-06-09, 16.83
2019-06-16, 15.79
2019-06-23, 15.00
2019-06-30, 15.73
2019-07-07, 13.21
2019-07-14, 13.28
2019-07-21, 13.50
2019-07-28, 12.62
2019-08-04, 15.67
2019-08-11, 19.83
2019-08-18, 20.07
2019-08-25, 17.35
2019-09-01, 19.17
2019-09-08, 17.07
2019-09-15, 14.61
2019-09-22, 14.49
2019-09-29, 16.24
2019-10-06, 18.30
2019-10-13, 17.99
2019-10-20, 13.97
2019-10-27, 13.77
2019-11-03, 12.83
2019-11-10, 12.67
2019-11-17, 12.69
2019-11-24, 12.71
2019-12-01, 11.95
2019-12-08, 14.76
2019-12-15, 14.62
2019-12-22, 12.40
2019-12-29, 12.84
2020-01-05, 13.77
2020-01-12, 13.24
2020-01-19, 12.31
2020-01-26, 13.33
2020-02-02, 17.05
2020-02-09, 15.92
2020-02-16, 14.36
2020-02-23, 15.46
2020-03-01, 31.94
2020-03-08, 36.76
2020-03-15, 57.79
2020-03-22, 74.62
2020-03-29, 62.75
2020-04-05, 53.08
2020-04-12, 44.24
2020-04-19, 39.97
2020-04-26, 35.93
2020-05-03, 37.19
2020-05-08, 31.44
}\chartthree

 % nicer legend
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},
} % 

\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw = none}}
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},}

\def\pft#1#2#3#4-#5-#6;{\edef\myshortyear{#3#4}}%

\begin{axis}[
width = 9cm,
height = 7cm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits={0.02,upper},
enlarge y limits={0.1, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={Indeks},
ylabel shift = 5pt,
ytick distance = 10,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=0, /tikz/.cd},
ymin=5,
%
% x axis ticks and style
xmin = 2019-05-08,
date coordinates in=x,
xtick distance = 31,
%xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chartthree}{date}, 
xticklabel={\pgfcalendar{tickcal}{\tick}{\tick}{\pgfcalendarshorthand{m}{.}}%
    \expandafter\pft\tick;%
    --\myshortyear},
x tick label style = {rotate=90}]
axis x line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}},       
xticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis x line shift}},
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [black, fill]
table [x=date,y=vix] from \chartthree \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a possible way. The month names are stored in

```
\newcommand\CustomMonthName[1]{%
\ifcase#1\relax
\or Jan \or Feb \or Mac \or Apr \or Mei \or Jun  \or Jul \or Ogos
\or Sep \or Okt \or Nov \or Dis \fi}
```

where I have changed `May` to `Mei`, and done the other ones you mentioned too. :) Any other English names can also be redefined as you choose.

The `\pft` function has been redefined to also fetch the month. We can then do

```
xticklabel={\expandafter\pft\tick;%
 \CustomMonthName{\mymonth}--\myshortyear},
```

as in

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    date, vix
    2019-05-05, 13.66
    2019-05-12, 17.86
    2019-05-19, 17.26
    2019-05-26, 15.76
    2019-06-02, 17.85
    2019-06-09, 16.83
    2019-06-16, 15.79
    2019-06-23, 15.00
    2019-06-30, 15.73
    2019-07-07, 13.21
    2019-07-14, 13.28
    2019-07-21, 13.50
    2019-07-28, 12.62
    2019-08-04, 15.67
    2019-08-11, 19.83
    2019-08-18, 20.07
    2019-08-25, 17.35
    2019-09-01, 19.17
    2019-09-08, 17.07
    2019-09-15, 14.61
    2019-09-22, 14.49
    2019-09-29, 16.24
    2019-10-06, 18.30
    2019-10-13, 17.99
    2019-10-20, 13.97
    2019-10-27, 13.77
    2019-11-03, 12.83
    2019-11-10, 12.67
    2019-11-17, 12.69
    2019-11-24, 12.71
    2019-12-01, 11.95
    2019-12-08, 14.76
    2019-12-15, 14.62
    2019-12-22, 12.40
    2019-12-29, 12.84
    2020-01-05, 13.77
    2020-01-12, 13.24
    2020-01-19, 12.31
    2020-01-26, 13.33
    2020-02-02, 17.05
    2020-02-09, 15.92
    2020-02-16, 14.36
    2020-02-23, 15.46
    2020-03-01, 31.94
    2020-03-08, 36.76
    2020-03-15, 57.79
    2020-03-22, 74.62
    2020-03-29, 62.75
    2020-04-05, 53.08
    2020-04-12, 44.24
    2020-04-19, 39.97
    2020-04-26, 35.93
    2020-05-03, 37.19
    2020-05-08, 31.44
}\chartthree

% nicer legend
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},
} % 

\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw = none}}
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},}

\def\pft#1#2#3#4-#5-#6;{\edef\myshortyear{#3#4}%
    \edef\mymonth{#5}} % new definition

% this is the code which redefines the months
\newcommand\CustomMonthName[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\relax
    \or Jan \or Feb \or Mar \or Apr \or Mei \or Jun  \or Jul \or Ogos
    \or Sep \or Okt \or Nov \or Dis \fi}

\begin{axis}[
width = 9cm,
height = 7cm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits={0.02,upper},
enlarge y limits={0.1, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={Indeks},
ylabel shift = 5pt,
ytick distance = 10,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=0, /tikz/.cd},
ymin=5,
%
% x axis ticks and style
xmin = 2019-05-08,
date coordinates in=x,
xtick distance = 31,
%xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chartthree}{date}, 
xticklabel={\expandafter\pft\tick;%
    \CustomMonthName{\mymonth}--\myshortyear}, % redefined command for xticks
x tick label style = {rotate=90}]
axis x line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}},       
xticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis x line shift}},
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [black, fill]
table [x=date,y=vix] from \chartthree \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you as always, and your point about the dataset is well taken (even under pressure, that was not acceptable and I apologise). To make amends, I have shortened the dataset, edited my question, and submitted an edit for your answer to make it even more illustrative / easier for future readers to use. Thank you, and I am sorry again :)

Comment: @Thev No worries!

Answer (score 8):

**Quick solution**:

```
% make sure dateplot lib is loaded first
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

% redefine pgfcalendar internals
\makeatletter
% defined in file pgfcalendar.code.tex
\def\pgfcalendarmonthshortname#1{%
  \pgfutil@translate{\ifcase#1\or Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or
    % here I have changed "May" to "Mei" as an example
    Mei\or Jun\or Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or
    Nov\or Dec\fi}%
}
\makeatother
```

**More elegant solution**:

The `dateplot` library of `pgfplots` package makes use of the internal macros provided by `pgfcalendar` library of `tikz` package. Since these internal macros already uses `\translate` from `translator` package, you can just provide more translations. This works for every use of  `pgfcalendar` library, hence I personally recommend it.

Use the following lines as preamble, then "May" is translated to "Mei" in the output.

```
\usepackage{translator}
\languagepath{Indonesian} % here I guess OP uses Indonesian
\deftranslation[to=Indonesian]{May}{Mei}
% more \deftranslation lines to translate other months into Indonesian

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
```

To use this translations for multiple `.tex` files, you can define a new dictionary file `translator-months-dictionary-Indonesian.dict` based on [`translator-months-dictionary-English.dict`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/translator/translator-months-dictionary-English.dict). See the user manual of [`translator`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/translator/translator.pdf) package.

Comment: Thank you! For my own learning - is there any reason that this type of solution might be less preferable than the accepted answer by @Schrodinger'sCat?

Comment: @Thev A full `translator` example is added. It is more general that works for every `tikz` example which uses `pgfcalendar` to show months. The quick solution avoids the tricky value passed to `xticklabel` option, in the cost of knowing what internal macro is used.